# No instance of overloaded function winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::SelectorItem::Content matches the argument list

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, uwp-xaml, c++-cx, c++-winrt

In C++/CX, I was able to do:

```
Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::SelectorItem item;
const wchar_t* str = L"someString";
item->Content = str;
```

But, when I do the equivalent in C++/WinRT,

```
winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::SelectorItem item;
const wchar_t* str = L"someString";
item.Content(str);
```

I get an error:

> No instance of overloaded function
> winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::SelectorItem::Content
> matches the argument list.

What am I missing?

Comment: `item.Content(winrt::box_value(str));`, [I think](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/boxing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Content` function expects something of type IInspectable, wchar_t is this not though. If you pass "primitives", you need to box them. The following works:

```cpp
winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::SelectorItem item;
const wchar_t* str = L"someString";
item.Content(box_value(str));
```